# Scala map function fails when transforming a list of tuples to a list of objects

Tags: scala

Let define a simple case class

```
case class Dummy(a: Int)
```

I try to transform `List[(Int, Int)]` to `List[Dummy]`using `List.map`.

Passing an anonymous function to `map` like this works fine:

```
val as = List((1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 9))
as.map(a => Dummy(a._2))
/* Output */
val res2: List[Dummy] = List(Dummy(1), Dummy(4), Dummy(9))
```

But when using `_` it fails:

```
as.map(Dummy(_._2))
/* Output */
1 |as.map(Dummy(_._2))
  |             ^
  |     Missing parameter type
  |
  |     I could not infer the type of the parameter _$1 of expanded function:
  |     _$1 => _$1._2.
```

Why?

FYI, it seems that `_._2` can be used if it is not inside the constructor `Dummy`:

```
as.map(_._2)
/* Output */
val res3: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 9)
```

Comment: `_._2` expands as `x => x._2`  and the expansion happens in the inner most scope, thus in thus case: `as.map(Dummy(_._2))` is `as.map(Dummy(x => x._2))` which is wrong in two ways. - Just use a named argument, the `_` syntax is a mistake.

Comment: also asked at https://users.scala-lang.org/t/scala-map-function-fails-when-transforming-a-list-of-tuples-to-a-list-of-class/8327